# Варианты решения и на сколько велика сложность задачи выбора оптимальной рекламы или исполнителей эффективного продвижения сайта в поисковых системах?

Tags: seo, оптимизация-сайтов, реклама, поисковая-оптимизация, продвижение

Существует задача привлечения бОльшего количества новых клиентов, но решить ее необходимо таким образом, что бы затраты ресурсов на рекламу, сео оптимизацию сайта и на прочее из этой области - отбивались, а не уменьшали прибыль. На сколько это сложная задача, что необходимо для ее эффективного решения? Организация занимается монтажом противопожарных систем.

Приведу негативный пример: сеошники год что то шаманили с сайтом и никакого эффекта их деятельность в итоге не принесла - такой вывод был сделан исходя из того что поток клиентов с сайта, которым они занимались, как был так и остался околонулевой, а клиенты привлекались другими путями. Каким образом не наступить на подобные грабли?

Answer (score 0):

> Существует задача привлечения бОльшего количества новых клиентов, но
> решить ее необходимо таким образом, что бы затраты ресурсов на
> рекламу, сео оптимизацию сайта и на прочее из этой области -
> отбивались, а не уменьшали прибыль. На сколько это сложная задача, что
> необходимо для ее эффективного решения?

Как ни банально это звучит, но вам может помогать использование полной поисковой оптимизации содержания вашего веб-сайта. Это моё утверждение основано на том факте что поисковая оптимизация есть база для дигитального маркетинга, который в свою очередь имеет цель повышения онлайн-видимости сущностей веб-сайта и повышение продаж.

Реклама получает информацию от содержания веб-страниц на которых представлены рекламируемые товары. И стоимость рекламы, её конкурентоспособность и эффективность имеет высокую зависимость от уровня поисковой оптимиации содержания представляющего рекламируемый продукт.

> Приведу негативный пример: сеошники год что то шаманили с сайтом и
> никакого эффекта их деятельность в итоге не принесла - такой вывод был
> сделан исходя из того что поток клиентов с сайта, которым они
> занимались, как был так и остался околонулевой, а клиенты привлекались
> другими путями. Каким образом не наступить на подобные грабли?

Нанимайте уполномоченных экспертов поисковой оптимизации, которые известны поисковикам и имеют подтверждение внешних источников информации, подтверждающих их уполномоченность. Для подробного понимания проверьте мой ответ на английской Кворе **[How can I buy SEO for my business? - Как я могу купить SEO для своего бизнеса?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-buy-SEO-for-my-business/answer/Nikolaj-Antonov)**:

> Ваш бизнес будет зависеть от компетентности, авторитета и надежности
> вашего кандидата, поэтому вам нужно приложить максимум усилий, чтобы
> выбрать лучшего.
>
> Проверьте надежность вашего кандидата на SEO с помощью наличия
> бизнес-информации на его веб-сайте: адрес, регистрационный номер,
> государственное учреждение, в котором зарегистрирован этот бизнес,
> номер плательщика НДС или налоговый идентификатор,
> бизнес-идентификаторы, часы работы и так далее. Проверьте, доступен ли
> Google Knowledge ID для бизнеса вашего кандидата. Для этого найдите на
> веб-сайте официальное название компании, просто введите это имя в
> адресной строке и нажмите. Проверьте, насколько ясна эта информация.
> Если этот бизнес зарегистрирован в Google My Business, то он имеет
> фрагмент Сети знаний Google в поисковой выдаче справа. Эксперты по
> поисковой оптимизации создают тестовую ссылку для этого фрагмента и
> устанавливают ее в деловой информации на своих сайтах. Например,
> перейдите на веб-сайт моей компании и в информации о компании нажмите
> кнопку с официальным названием. Посмотрите, насколько четко указаны
> услуги и цены на сайте вашего кандидата. Возможно, существует даже
> образец соглашения. Проверьте, какие публикации по поисковой
> оптимизации есть у вашего кандидата и насколько они заслуживают
> доверия. Если что-то не внушает доверия, просто убегайте от такого
> кандидата.

При выборе кандидата-эксперта не фокусируйте ваше внимание на прошлых успехах кандидата. Это связано с тем фактом что во многих странах законодательство запрещает разглашать какую то внутреннюю информацию о бизнесе в котором мог работать кандидат. Более полезно фокусировать внимание на общедоступных публикациях кандидата и,разумеется на его уполномоченности.

Сложность поисковой оптимизации зависит от конкретной цели и от количества сущностей веб-сайта. Под сложностью для уполномоченного эксперта я понимаю не непреодолимое препятствие, но большой объем работы по созданию связанных данных всех сущностей содержания, внутри веб-сайта и с внешними источниками информации.